# Is there a DRY(er) way to add items to an array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dry

I have a snippet of code that works without issue. However, I feel like it is kind of long for what it does and I felt like I repeated my self a lot. This is a validation snippet that checks a form for all input fields and displays an error message with what you are missing (if you are) once you submit.

```
$scope.save = function() {
  var post = new FormData();
  post.append("title", $scope.post.title);
  post.append("photo", $scope.photo);
  post.append("body", $scope.post.body);
  post.append("truncBody", $scope.post.truncBody);

  if(!$scope.post.title || !$scope.photo || !$scope.post.body || !$scope.post.truncBody){
    var thingsLeft= [];
    if(!$scope.post.title){
      thingsLeft.push(" Title");
    }
    if(!$scope.photo){
      thingsLeft.push(" Cover Image")
    }
    if(!$scope.post.body){
      thingsLeft.push(" Body");
    }
    if(!$scope.post.truncBody){
      thingsLeft.push(" Summary");
    }

    Messages.error("Please fill out all fields. Fields left:" + thingsLeft);
    return;
  }else{
    post to server
  } 
}
```

Again, this works perfectly, no errors, looks great client side. All I want to know is if there is a better/shorter/more DRY way of writing this.

Comment: Maybe try looping through the form elements instead of doing an if for each one.

Comment: Another DRY(er) way to do would be to allow directives to handle this for you instead of manually adding each validations inside your controller logic, which is also a very good Angular way to do things.

Comment: Something like this: [**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/AwBIIw55Dr3DI34RV4jt?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really ended up having a lot of that sort of code, you could write a helper function:

```
function pushIf(array) {
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i += 2)
    if (arguments[i]) array.push(arguments[i + 1]);
}
```

then

```
pushIf(thingsLeft,
  !$scope.post.title, " Title ",
  !$scope.photo, " Cover Image ",
  !$scope.post.body, " Body",
  !$scope.post.truncBody, " Summary"
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If `thingsLeft` is empty, no things are left, you may omit the doubly listed props in the `if`, that would annoy me personally:

```
  var thingsLeft= [];
  if(!$scope.post.title){
     thingsLeft.push(" Title");
  }
  if(!$scope.photo){
     thingsLeft.push(" Cover Image")
  }
  if(!$scope.post.body){
     thingsLeft.push(" Body");
  }
  if(!$scope.post.truncBody){
     thingsLeft.push(" Summary");
  }

  if ( thingsLeft.length > 0 ) {
    Messages.error("Please fill out all fields. Fields left:" + thingsLeft);
    return;
  }else{
    post to server
  }
```

Comment: Well, the other guy deleted his answer, lol, looks like I had the right idea, just put in some unnecessary code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array of the required properties and `hasOwnProperty()`. Something along these lines:

```
var requiredFields = ['post.title', 'photo', 'post.body', 'post.truncBody'];
var missingFields = [];

for (field in requiredFields) {
  if (!$scope.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
    missingFields.push(field);
  }
}
```